# Why do I get nil error in this case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Indeed, @community has 4 tags so that it shouldn't return nil error.
However in this case, it returns nil error like this. Why and how can I fix?

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass):
```

My code

```
<% @community.tags.each do |tag| %><% tag_strings = tag_strings + tag.name + "," %><% end %>
<%= render 'layouts/twitter', :tag => tag_strings + @community.community_name %>
```

Comment: Did you initialize `tag_strings` to `""` before this code?

Comment: @DOgbert No. I didn't

Comment: Well then that's what you should have done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tag_strings` is not initialized when the iteration starts. Perhaps you want to join all tags.  If so then try
`tag_strings = @community.tags.map(&:name).join(", ")`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this more neatly like so:

```
<%= render 'layouts/twitter', :tag => @community.tags.collect(&:name).join(",") + @community.community_name %>
```

Answer (score 0):

..or even more neatly...

```
class Community < ActiveRecord::Base
  def tags_string
    "#{tags.collect(&:name).join(',')} #{community_name}"
  end
end

= render 'layouts/twitter', tag: @community.tags_string
```